# How to make label.txt from keras model

Tags: python, android-studio, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I trained model on keras on two classes. I then converted it into .tflite by this code:

```
# Converting a SavedModel to a TensorFlow Lite model. 
saved_model_dir = r'C:\Users\Munib\New folder\my_model.h5' 
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(saved_model_dir)
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(loaded_model)# .from_saved_model(saved_model_dir) 
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("my_model_converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

When i studied further on internet on how to import .tflite model on android studio. They said i must have two files:

1. my_model_converted_model.tflite
2. label.txt

I am now confused on how to make labels from keras can someone tell me Thank you

Comment: Guys, This is the website i following:https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/recognize-flowers-with-tensorflow-on-android/#4

Comment: Yes I am following the same tutorial I have experience in android app development but I am completely new to Tensorflow and ML I am not understanding from where to download these two files? I did runtime run all.. Also started with the project in android studio added dependencies but I am really not getting where to download this model and other file? Plz help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your model has 2 classes, the output of your model might look like this -- eg: [0.12, 0.88]. If the first output, i.e, 0.12, corresponds to the probability that the prediction is "Yes" and the second output, i.e, 0.88, corresponds to the probability that the prediction is "Now", then create new file named "labels.txt" with contents:

```
Yes
No
```

That's it! It's that simple :)

*Please mark this as an **accepted answer** if this is resolved your issue :)*